# Warm start preparation failed: 1262 error in CPLEX while iterating over several scenarios

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex

I am trying to run a model several times while increasing a certain coefficient of a variable in every iteration in CPLEX. In order to do this, I have had a look at the example file within the CPLEX install directory, named "mulprod". I am using the same code as shown in the example within my model, however I have done some changes to it in order to adapt the example to my own model.

More specifically, the changes I have done so far include:

- Changing the variable "capFlour" into "coeff", which is an integer variable I use in order to indicate the coefficient of the variable I am willing to increase in every iteration.
- Changing the part of the code where we use the objective value into my problem's own objective value, which is 51.

I will demonstrate the changes I have done below:

```
//The original code (from the example "mulprod"):

main {
...
var capFlour = produce.Capacity["flour"];
...
data.Capacity["flour"] = capFlour;
...
if (Math.abs(cplex.getObjValue() - 393.5)>=0.01) { //Objective value of the example model
  status = -1;
}
...
}

//My code

main {
...
var capFlour = produce.coeff;
...
data.coeff = capFlour;
...
if (Math.abs(cplex.getObjValue() - 51)>=0.01) { //Objective value of my model
  status = -1;
}
...
}
```

Running the model gives me the following information in the Scripting Log:

```
Solve with capFlour = 1

OBJECTIVE: 51
warm start preparation failed: 1262
```

The value 1 is the initial value of "coeff" and solving the model without the main method (using coeff=1) gives me the objective value of 51.

What might be causing me to get this error and how may I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I was getting the error message was because my model is a Mixed Integer problem and not a LP model. Apparently, in order to create a base for the model using thisOplModel.generate() is not applicable for Mixed Integer problems. Opting this line out solved this problem for me.